# Abstract superclass for both handle and non-handle subclass

Tags: matlab, interface, abstract, handle

I need to know if there is a way in matlab to define interface superclass for both handle and non-handle subclasses? If in hierarchy there is a handle class, all classes must be handle too and in matlab the interface is defined as abstract class. So it can't be done this way.

```
class A < handle
....
end

class AA < A
....
    methods 
        function foo
        end
    end
end

class B
....
    methods
        function foo
    end
end
```

I want to create some kind of container with classes AA (handle) and B (non-handle) to ensure they both have function foo. Is there way to do this?

Comment: What's your question? You asked if something was possible, then stated that it is not...

Comment: Is there another way to ensure definition of some methods in both handle and non-handle classes (from different hierarchies) ?

Comment: You can inherit from multiple classes, this may make what you want possible. https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/subclass-syntax.html

Comment: Yes, but then both superclasses must be either handle or non-handle. If I do this I get error: 'If a class defines superclasses, all or none must be handle classes.'.

Comment: Just edited my question. Hope it will be more understandable now.

Comment: You don’t need inheritance to give each class a function `foo`. Just write the function. Or you can write a generic `foo` that checks the input type and acts accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
classdef (Abstract, HandleCompatible) A
    methods (Abstract)
        function foo
    end
end

classdef AA < A & handle
    methods
        function foo
        ...
        end
    end
end

classdef B < A
    methods
        function foo
        ...
        end
    end
end
```

Here you are marking `A` as `Abstract`, with an abstract method `foo`. So `AA` and `B` must both implement `foo`. You also mark `A` as `HandleCompatible`, which means that subclasses can be handles.

Then `AA` inherits from both `A` and `handle`, but `B` inherits only from `A` and is a value class. Both implement `foo`.

Note that you may need to take care in the way that you implement foo in each class, as the necessary function signature can vary between handle and value classes.